# psutil on Linux shows no CPU Core Temperatures

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, psutil, lm-sensors

My Python 3 script uses `psutil` v5.6.2 to extract various information about the current system (Ubuntu 18.04, AMD Ryzen 2700X) such as the CPU core temperatures.

**Problem:** However running the following code to obtain the core temperatures

```
import psutil
psutil.sensors_temperatures()
```

returns an empty dict

> {}

even though running `lmsensors` (sensors version 3.4.0 with libsensors version 3.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04) does return the temperatures

```
$ sensors
```

```
nouveau-pci-1f00
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.91 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.19 V)
temp1:        +36.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +79.4°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +89.4°C
```

Why is `psutil` not giving us the temperatures we need, and how can we solve this problem?

*PS: Also looked into [`Pysensors`](https://bitbucket.org/blackjack/pysensors/src) but it does not support Python 3. Any suggestions on a Python 3 alternative?*

Comment: Which version are you using of `psutil`, it gives me `module 'psutil' has no attribute 'sensors_temperatures'` for `v5.6.3`

Comment: @JainilPatel I am running `psutil` in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I am using `v5.6.2`. This function can be found in the docs https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_temperatures

Comment: @JainilPatel Ubuntu is considered a Unix based system, so I think it should work? The link to the `sensors_temperatures` function in the docs specifically stated **Availability: Linux, FreeBSD**

Comment: Looking briefly at both projects I think `psutil` reads temperatures from `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon...` while `lm sensors` reads directly from chips.

Answer (score 1):

Pysensors does support python3 as of now